# How should I lubricate my gears?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

I am doing an experiment testing different types of gears, the gears are fairly small, with gear 1 being approx. 35mm in diameter and gear 2 being 45mm in diameter, and both are meshed together, there are also around 15mm wide. the gears will be rotating at a max speed of 2000 RPM also. I want to test a lot of the same gears with different constrains, but want the lubrication to remain the same, since these gears tangential velocity are not that fast, many suggest Grease as lubrication, but I want to use the exact same amount of grease each time I test the gears so it does not affect the results, another maybe the oil bath method, which will allow me to put an exact amount of oil each time however might seem a bit overkill for gears which are so small.

does anyone know Which method of lubrication will be better and if it is grease, what are the suggestions to make sure I use the exact same amount each time so It does not affect the results.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one solution would be to spray the lubricant (provided it's fluid enough) on the gears

[image]

*Figure 1: source [machinery lubrication](https://www.machinerylubrication.com/Read/614/airless-spray-gear-lubrication)*

By spraying you can make sure that you control the flow of the lubricant, and therefore you can control parameters like:

- heat abduction
- estimated thickness of film on the gears
- etc

---

## Splash lubrication

Another solution is **Splash lubrication** (but not optimal for the parameters you have provided).

[image]

*Figure 2:  Splash lubrication [addinol](https://addinol.de/en/service-en/expert-tip/splash-lubrication/)*

The advantage is that it is more cost effective. The only problem is that with the dimensions of the gear only at the maximum rpm you are at the low end of the recommended velocity.

I.e. Assuming that the 45[mm] is rotating at 2000[rpm], then the velocity will be about 4.7[m/s]. (if the 35 mm is @2000[rpm] then the velocity is about 3.67[m/s]).

The recommended range velocities for the different types of lubrication can be seen in the following image

[image]

*Figure 3:  Ranges of tangential speed (m-s) for spur gears and bevel gears source [KHK gears](https://khkgears.net/new/gear_knowledge/gear_technical_reference/lubrication-of-gears.html)*

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, would this method require constant spraying or could I spray once before the start of testing and leave it.

Comment: The best case (if you can afford it because it has an added cost), is to continuously apply the lubricant.

Comment: each test will only be operating for around 90 minutes, does this impact how much should be used?

Comment: Actually no, because you can re-circulate the oil (maybe with a small filter to remove the particles). There are ready systems, with the pump, filter, sprayer you can look at.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions if I use grease lubricant because it is on low end of speed to make sure the grease amount stays constant each test?

Comment: The point of the grease is that it stays more or less where you put it. For a 90 minute test I think you should be ok, in any case. Just make sure that you cover the gear box, because at 2000[rpm] you might have pieces of grease flying around  in the first few minutes.

Comment: You can measure the amount of grease you put in (either weight or volume) and use the same amount each time. You will need to thoroughly clean the gear box after each test though.

Comment: @mikey5512 what did you do in the end? Did it work?

Comment: Hi Nmech, I used grease by measuring the mass before and cleaning it before each time. thanks